# How to correctly iterate over filtered AWS bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm having trouble working through the boto3 API. I'm trying to grab the data from files in a specific folder in an S3 bucket. The closest I can get to getting this to work looks like this:

```
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(name='mybucket')
for f in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='raw/2019/12/05/08'):
    print(f.get()['Body'].read())
```

There are 5 files in the corresponding folder, and it seems like this loop reads all 5 of them for each iteration of the loop, I think. What's going on here? How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Well you have a loop, so of course it will go through all contents of the bucket in the filtered folder. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean that for each iteration of the loop, *every* file in the folder gets printed out

Comment: You are iterating over files inside the prefix path mentioned, and you are basically performing a GET which will give you an s3 resource object on which when get 'Body' and read from it, it starts downloading the files, What else you r expecting here?

Comment: @theQman Your code works perfectly fine for me. However, if you are specifying a directory, you should add a `/` at the end of the Prefix. Otherwise, it will include other folders that being with `08`. Use: `Prefix='raw/2019/12/05/08/'`